# Do I need writer/reader synchronization if I don't care if reader will read stale data?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Let I have a reader thread. Reader has a vector of bools. Size of the vector isn't changed and always known.  Reader reads some data from another source, calculates an index from the data and checks if vector[index] == true. If true, Reader sends data further. If not, drops data.
Let I have a writer thread. Writer makes vector[index] true or false.
Do I really need a mutex for vector if I don't bother that some extra data chunks will be sent or some chunks will be lost? Is it absolutely safe to use a vector in this way?

Comment: Why not use array of atomics for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading and writing the same value, however small, from multiple threads without synchronization, is a [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races), a form of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Even if the hardware guarantees cache coherency (as in x86), the [C++ memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) is defined such that in the absence of synchronization each thread is assumed to be executing in isolation. Then according to the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) the compiler is allowed to optimize away and reorder memory accesses any way it sees fit, so the behavior of a program with a data race becomes unpredictable. The reader thread may never "see" any updated value, for example. Or the writer may not write anything to memory until the thread is finished, or write in a different order. The behavior may change between compiler versions, optimization levels, etc.

Note that *synchronization* doesn't mean a *mutex*, an *atomic* will do too (a vector of atomics is somewhat complicated, but is possible too, though my feeling is that a userspace mutex would be more efficient).

---

Bonus note: don't forget about [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads.html) when accessing the same vector from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

As rustyx already indicated, atomics could do the trick.

If you just care about reading the value at some point in the future and not suffer from a data race (so the lack of a happens before relation between the write and the read), then it would be sufficient to set the flags using a memory_order_release and get the flags using a memory_order_acquire.

On the X86; which uses the TSO memory model, all regular stores are release stores and all regular loads are acquire loads. So on a hardware level there is no price to pay. Only the compiler will be prevented from doing certain reorderings.

The expensive write on an X86 is the memory_order_sec_cst. In that case, the store is put on the store buffer and the CPU stops executing any loads till the store buffer has been drained. With a memory_order_sec_cst, the store is placed on the store buffer and the CPU can continue with the next instruction (even loads); so the CPU is not stalled.